# Sidebar Widgets Not Showing Up in Wordpress Admin Panel

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

So seemingly overnight (I don't know what happened) all my widgets disappeared out of my sidebar, and don't show up in the admin panel so I can't add them back.

My website is http://dubstep-remixes.com so you can see that there is no sidebar (there used to be one).

Here is a picture of my admin panel -- you can see that there are no widget options there. If I add the one profile widget it does show up on the website, so it's a matter of getting the widgets back in the admin panel

[image: http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/9993/widgets.png]

Help me please!

Comment: You may want to add more details like what event caused this to happen, like wordpress upgrade or theme upgrade or some plugin upgrade for example.

Comment: That's part of the problem, I have no idea. I'm looking for any generic solution to try out

Comment: If you have a local setup where you can reproduce this issue, you will be able to better debug it. For example, I'd start with setting up a different theme.

Comment: I tried switching themes and the same thing happens. There are no inactive widgets, just the Profile active widget, and nothing listed in my sidebar. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and tracked it down to my sidebar id's having capital letters in ID. as identified by the [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)

> 'id' => 'homeNew'

to

> 'id' => 'homenew'

Worked like a charm.